# Low beam headlight on 2004 Honda Accord

Tags: honda, accord, headlight

I am changing the low-beam headlight on a 2004 Honda Accord.  The shop manual says to go in through the wheelwell, but removing the inner fender cover doesn't seem to provide enough access.  Anyone with experience?  Thanks.

Comment: It may be a case that you need to be able to hold and remove / fit the bulb by holding just the end of one terminal with the tips of your first and second fingers (no thumb) and once in, use the third finger to advance the clip - at least that is about what i have to do for changing the headlight bulbs on mine.... Just be careful with the language when you drop it - you never know who is behind you :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which side you are replacing, but on 2003-2007 Honda Accord, both should be accessibly from the engine bay.

- The driver side headlight easily accessible after removing the
  battery.
- The passenger side is much easier to access.

This YouTube video shows it well. https://youtu.be/I-5f-XhNbFQ

Comment: Found this agreeing with you @CharlieRB: [CarGuru Article](https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/Discussion-c2091_ds39251)

Comment: Just if you want a link/resource to add. ;)

Comment: I appreciate the responses.  I had reviewed the youtube videos, which caused my question.  I am changing both, and I am concerned about losing radio presets, etc. if the battery is removed.  On the passenger side, the space seems pretty tight, so I was looking for someone's experience of going through the wheelwell. . .